# jquery form submission

Tags: html, forms

I am using jQuery+JSON combination something like this:

test.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="coupon.js"></script>

<form action='_test.php' method='post' class='ajaxform'>
 <input type='text' name='txt' value='Test Text'>
 <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<div id='testDiv'></div>
```

_test.php:

```
<?php
      // Code here to deal with form submitted data.
      $arr = array( 'testDiv' => 'Form is successfully submitted.' );
      echo json_encode( $arr );
?>
```

coupon.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        for(var id in data) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                        }
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

**Now what i wanted is that when a successful form is submitted then without any page refresh a message should be displayed under the div testDiv. 
I was hoping that this script would help but when a form is being submitted then the page goes to .../_test.php and displays a white blank page except the following  -**

{"testDiv":"Form is successfully submitted."}

**Firebug does not report any error with any of the scripts**.Please help.Thanks in advanvce

The same can be seen at http://174.132.194.155/~kunal17/devbuzzr/deals/5-discount-on-all-guitars. Click on "**grab coupon**" link and then click on **submit** inside the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the link you provided, but the coupon.js script that I found ends with "return true," not "return false." Have you tried changing that to "return false"?